# Label with Auto Length increment as per need but not width

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm stuck on a code where I need to make Label AutoSize with fixed width. I've tried

```
Label1.AutoSize = True
Label1.MaximumSize = (FixedWidthInteger,0)
```

but its still not resizing the length when text if overflow. I've tried to make Panel also AutoSize Enabled to let Label resizing itself but both ways doesn't work. Thank you if you can help me with this please.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information.  What is the value of `FixedWidthInteger`?  What is the original text?  What is the new text?  Post as much code as needed that duplicates the issue for us.

Comment: Actually iam making a messenger Chat UI where Chat bubble can resize itself (in height) as per user's messenger length but need a fixed width.

Comment: You forgot to set the `MinimumSize` (same value as `.MaximumSize`)

Comment: I think if i set MinimumSize same as MaximumSize then it will not Grow or Shrink.. Like a fixed size bubble.

Comment: Nope, because the Height is set to `0` (automatic)

Comment: I will try now.. Thanks <3

Comment: You might also want to look at the MultiLine and/or WordWrap properties

Comment: @Jimi I'm guessing the issue is the user enters "Hello" and the width is going to be that minimum, so there will be a lot of extra space.

Comment: I tried "You forgot to set the MinimumSize (same value as .MaximumSize): this and i think it works well in autoresizing the height but when the Label resize itself, the Panel also resizing and when Panel resize, It hide the other controls which are just next to the Panel (Down side)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sV0xiWe.png

like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed. I just change the Anchor to all sides of the Panel and its resizing well now.